# How to write the query statement of the total number of time series by paging in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

My data structure settings in Apache IoTDB is like this:  `root.xxx.xxx.device.property`. I want to query the total time series number from the device level separated by paging. However, I checked the official guide and all the questions, but did not find any specific query statement example on paging scenarios. Does anyone know how to write this query statement?

Answer (score 0):

If your devices are in non-aligned form (which should be the usual case), then the total time series by paging cannot be directly obtained. You can add `limit` and `offset` in your query statement of Apache IoTDB, and obtain the time series number page by page, then add them all together.